# Using R: I want to create a contingency table with a 4 category variable

Tags: r, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

Currently I have data on SEX and outcome.

For outcome there are 4 different values possible 1, 2, 3, 4.

I want to create a contingency table (so that I can eventually do a Fisher test) such that I get:

```
          SEX
outcome F     M
1
Not 1
```

My current script in R:

```
xtabs(~outcome+SEX, data=data)
       SEX
outcome  F  M
      1  9 20
      2 10  6
      3 11 27
      4 16 42
```

Comment: Welcome to our site! Have a look at our [help/on-topic] to see the kind of question that are within the scope of our site - this is a programming question more than a statistical one, so I think it would make sense to migrate it to Stack Overflow. (We can do that for you, so there is no need for you to cross-post it there yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  SEX=sample(c("M", "F"), 100, T), 
  outcome=sample(1:4, 100, T)
)
xtabs(~outcome+SEX, data=data)
#        SEX
# outcome  F  M
#       1 11 10
#       2 12 13
#       3 11 21
#       4 14  8
( tab <- xtabs(~I(outcome==1L)+SEX, data=data) )
#                SEX
# I(outcome == 1)  F  M
#           FALSE 37 42
#           TRUE  11 10
dimnames(tab) <- list(outcome=c("not 1", "1"), SEX=colnames(tab))
tab
#        SEX
# outcome  F  M
#   not 1 37 42
#   1     11 10
```